# Show Cell Content

Tags: excel, vba

I'm just starting with VBA and I need. I want to move the contents from Sheet1 to Sheet2 by using For function since I want it to run in the background but I can't seem to be able to reflect the contents in Sheet2. If I step through the codes, it's doing it's function fine but it's not reflecting on the actual worksheet.

```
Dim CellCount As Long 
Dim CellCon As Long
Dim Val As String ' Holds cell Content

CellCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

    For CellCon = 1 To CellCount

        Val = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Cells(CellCon)
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(CellCount).Value = Val

    Next CellCon
```

Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(CellCount).Value = Val
```

should be changed to

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(CellCon).Value = Val
```

Using similar names for variables that have different purposes can lead to confusion, sometimes.

Comment: Thanks! That really did it but I have another question. The contents reflected is not in Cell A1 but started at Cell A2. Can you help me understand this as well?

Comment: @Marco  `CellCon` is initially `1`, and you are using it as your `RowOffset` argument in the `Range.Offset` function,  If you want to start in `A1`, you need to subtract `1` from that value.